# How to define a implicit (given) Conversion for Generic Types?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scala-3, existential-type

I want to use the **Scala 3** [Implicit Conversion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-implicit-conversions.html).

I have the following construct that I want to migrate:

```
  implicit def toTesterObjectScenario[In <: Product](
                                   decisionDmn: DecisionDmn[In, _]
                                ): DmnTesterObject[In] =
    DmnTesterObject(decisionDmn, defaultDmnPath(decisionDmn.decisionDefinitionKey))
```

I tried:

```
  given Conversion[DecisionDmn[_ <: Product, _], DmnTesterObject[_ <: Product]] with
    def apply(decisionDmn: DecisionDmn[_ <: Product, _]): DmnTesterObject[_ <: Product] =
      DmnTesterObject(decisionDmn, defaultDmnPath(decisionDmn.decisionDefinitionKey))
```

This compiles but does not work when running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'camundala.dmn.DmnTesterConfigCreator$DmnTesterObject camundala.dmn.DmnTesterConfigCreator.toTesterObjectScenario$(camundala.dmn.DmnTesterConfigCreator, camundala.bpmn.DecisionDmn)'
    at valiant.bpmn.dmn.BpmnDmnTester$.toTesterObjectScenario(BpmnDmnTester.scala:11)
```

This does not even compile:

```
  given Conversion[DecisionDmn[_ <: Product, _], DmnTesterObject[_ <: Product]] with
    def apply[In <: Product](decisionDmn: DecisionDmn[In, _]): DmnTesterObject[In] =
      DmnTesterObject(decisionDmn, defaultDmnPath(decisionDmn.decisionDefinitionKey))
```

Is this not possible or how it is done?

Comment: Your code is not self-contained. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `DecisionDmn[_ <: Product, _]`, `DmnTesterObject[_ <: Product]` are existential types (with respect to all type parameters). So you're providing a conversion different from original (between different types than in original).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a given instance of type `Conversion[DecisionDmn[In, _], DmnTesterObject[In]` where `In <: Product`.

This is how you can add a type parameter to a given instance:

```scala
given [In <: Product]: Conversion[DecisionDmn[In, _], DmnTesterObject[In]] with
  def apply(decisionDmn: DecisionDmn[In, _]): DmnTesterObject[In] = ???
```